# Rotating a 2-d array by 90 degrees

Tags: arrays, algorithm, rotation

A frequent question that props up during array manipulation exercises is to rotate a two dimensional array by 90 degrees. There are a few SO posts that answer how to do it in a variety of programming languages. My question is to clarify one of the answers that is out there and explore what sort of thought-process is required in order to get to the answer in an organic manner.

The solution to this problem that I found goes as follows:

```
public static void rotate(int[][] matrix,int n)
{
  for( layer = 0;layer < n/2;++layer){
      int first = layer;
      int last = n -1 - layer;
      for(int i = first;i<last;++i){
        int offset = i - first;
        int top = matrix[first][i];
        matrix[first][i] = matrix[last-offset][first];
        matrix[last-offset][first] = matrix[last][last-offset];
        matrix[last][last-offset] = matrix[i][last];
        matrix[i][last] = top;
       }
    }
}
```

I have somewhat of an idea what the code above is trying to do, it is swapping out the extremities/corners by doing a four-way swap and doing the same for the other cells separated by some offset.

Stepping through this code I know it works, what I do not get is the mathematical basis for the above given algorithm. What is the rationale behind the 'layer','first','last' and the offset?

How did 'last' turn out to be `n-1-layer`? Why is the offset `i-first`? What is the offset in the first place?

If somebody could explain the genesis of this algorithm and step me through the thought process to come up with the solution, that will be great.

Thanks

Comment: just run it in a debugger or print the intermediate results ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to break down the big task (rotating a square matrix) into smaller tasks.

First, a square matrix can be broken into concentric square rings. The rotation of a ring is independent from the rotation of other rings, so to rotate the matrix just rotate each of the rings, one by one. In this case, we start at the outermost ring and work inward. We count the rings using `layer` (or `first`, same thing), and stop when we get to the middle, which is why it goes up to `n/2`. (It is worth checking to make sure this will work for odd and even `n`.) It is useful to keep track of the "far edge" of the ring, using `last = n - 1 - layer`. For instance, in a 5x5 matrix, the first ring starts at `first=0` and ends at `last=4`, the second ring starts at `first=1` and ends at `last=3` and so on.

How to rotate a ring? Walk right along the top edge, up along the left edge, left along the bottom edge and down along the right edge, all at the same time. At each step swap the four values around. The coordinate that changes is `i`, and the number of steps is `offset`. For example, when walking around the second ring, `i` goes {1,2,3} and `offset` goes {0,1,2}.

Comment: The "(or `first`, same thing)" comment is potentially confusing -- `layer` and `first` happen to always be the same number, but conceptually they're different.  `Layer` is used to count which concentric ring we're in, while `first` and `last` track the start and end of each edge.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So when the seasoned algorithmist gets the last = n -1 - layer and the offset to be i - first, they are just observing the pattern based on walking the ring? My question might seem a little odd but what I am trying to get at is how to get to the expressions n-1-layer and i-first based on the characteristics of the 2-d array. What I am trying to capture here is the thought process behind solving such problems, some of which you have articulated quite nicely in your response.

Comment: @sc_ray: The method is to break the problem down into simpler problems; it turns out to be swapping four points around and iterating over the square. One way to iterate over the square is by rings, and one way to iterate over a ring is by using `n-1-layer` and `i-first`. If this isn't clear, I suggest trying an easier problem first, like iterating over the points of a rectangle or triangle one at a time (not four at a time).